# Spring MongoDB: Projecting Array field size if it exists

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an Array field `replies` in my document, which may or may not exist. If it exists, I want to return its size otherwise return 0. Below is my projection code. For documents that contain `replies` field with elements in it, it is returning 0.

```
 ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project("title", "datePosted", "likes").
        and(ConditionalOperators.ifNull(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("replies").length()).then(0)).as("repliesCount");
```

Reading the MongoDB reference [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/), it is pretty straight forward but somehow it is not working.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Sample Data

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9e3873d022d154c54c2969"),
"title" : "Is this a nice place to meet some interesting people?",
"datePosted" : ISODate("2020-04-21T00:04:03.731Z"),
"views" : 0,
"likes" : 0,
"active" : true
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9e2f37d022d154c54c2961"),
"title" : "I am posting a quick discussion",
"datePosted" : ISODate("2020-04-20T23:24:39.768Z"),
"views" : 120,
"likes" : 4,
"active" : true,
"replies" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9e2f69d022d154c54c2963"),
        "reply" : "This is the first reply",
        "datePosted" : ISODate("2020-04-20T23:25:29.608Z"),
        "likes" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9e2f69d022ad4c54c2964"),
        "reply" : "This is another reply",
        "datePosted" : ISODate("2020-04-20T23:25:29.608Z"),
        "likes" : 0
    }
]
}
```

**Root Cause**

The solution provided by @valijon is correct. The problem lies in the POJO `DiscussionDoc` to which the result is mapped.

```
@Document(collection = "discussions")
public class DiscussionDoc {

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

  private String title;
  private LocalDateTime datePosted;
  private int views;
  private int likes;

  @Transient
  private int repliesCount;
  private boolean active;

  @Field(value = "replies")
  private List<ReplyDoc> replyList;
}
```

Removing `@Transient` it works. I am using `@Transient` on `repliesCount` because I do not want to persist this field when persisting a `DiscussionDoc`. There is no usefulness of persisting this field. But it will be used to hold total reply count when fetching a `DiscussionDoc`. But `@Transient` is somehow not letting `repliesCount` be set when a `DiscussionDoc` is fetched. I have removed `@Transient` to fix the problem. But what to do about `repliesCount` field now being persisted in DB?

Comment: I hope it's what you want https://mongoplayground.net/p/miz8g2mNpbP

Answer (score 0):

You were almost close:

```
ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project("title", "datePosted", "likes").
    and(ArrayOperators.arrayOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("replies").then(Collections.emptyList())).length()).as("repliesCount");
```

Equivalent to:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "title": 1,
    "datePosted": 1,
    "likes": 1,
    "repliesCount": {
      "$size": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$replies",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Workaround:** You may use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) serializer to get this calculated value:

```
private static final Gson g = new GsonBuilder().create();
...

List<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, 
    mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(DiscussionDoc.class), Document.class)
        .getMappedResults();

return result.stream()
    .map(doc -> g.fromJson(doc.toJson(), DiscussionDoc.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I see what you did. But it is still returning `repliesCount` 0.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary share your sample data please

Comment: Added sample data to the question.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary It works as expected https://mongoplayground.net/p/x3Mt48b2w8P. Maybe you are running TypedAggregation?

Comment: Nope I am using regular aggregation.

Comment: @meenaChaudhary can you post please full Aggregation + model

Comment: I have found the root cause for the problem. Take a look.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary I've updated my answer with workaround, check if it meets your expectations